# Is there a way to use cURL commands in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, rest, curl, azure-data-factory

So I am trying to create a Pipeline in Azure Data Factory and part of the process involves uploading a CSV to a temporary URL generated earlier in the Pipeline by an earlier REST API request. The API's documentation say's to use a cURL command or "a similar application". I have gotten the cURL command to work on my local environment but have had no luck doing it in ADF. the cURL command I am currently using is `curl --upload-file "<file location>" "<api URL>" --ssl-no-revoke -v`

While ADF supports web requests, it does not seem to support cURL commands at least directly. Currently I am trying to automate the cURL command through a Automation Account which runs a PowerShell Script and then use a web hook to continue from there within the pipeline but I have my doubt that this will work due to having to pass the temporary URL from the pipeline to the PowerShell script.

The questions can be summed up as follows:

- Is it possible to put a cURL command in a web request? I have not found any good examples of this as most cURL commands seem to take place in PowerShell and Command Prompt
- Is there some ADF functionality I am not aware of that runs cURL commands?
- What are the alternatives to cURL that I could use for this process? Are they friendlier than cURL when it comes to ADF?
- Any other potential advice I may need to know

I appreciate any input on this matter!

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do that is by creating your own batch / *.bat files which have the curl commands in it and execute them from server side , you may save results on text files which you can also read them from your server side .

[Read more here](https://superuser.com/questions/815692/how-can-i-apply-quotes-to-a-url-in-a-bat-script)